# pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError while sending traps

Tags: net-snmp, pysnmp

I am trying to send traps to snmp receiver using net-snmp and pysnmp. while sending the logs getting below error. This is happening only for time field. Could please some one help with this issue. Let me know if any other information is required.

```
failed to cast value <OctetString value object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:4>, subtypeSpec <ConstraintsIntersection object, consts <ValueSizeConstraint object, consts 0, 65535>>, encoding iso-8859-1, payload [2020-11-2,13:49:17.0,+2:0]>: <ConstraintsInter
section object, consts <ValueSizeConstraint object, consts 0, 65535>, <ValueSizeConstraint object, consts 8, 11>> failed at: ValueConstraintError("<ValueSizeConstraint object, consts 8, 1
1> failed at: ValueConstraintError(b'2020-11-2,13:49:17.0,+2:0')") at NbiEventTimecaused by <class 'pyasn1.type.error.ValueConstraintError'>: <ConstraintsIntersection object, consts <Valu
eSizeConstraint object, consts 0, 65535>, <ValueSizeConstraint object, consts 8, 11>> failed at: ValueConstraintError("<ValueSizeConstraint object, consts 8, 11> failed at: ValueConstrain
tError(b'2020-11-2,13:49:17.0,+2:0')") at NbiEventTime
```

The code

```py
def send_notification(conf, notification):
    next(sendNotification( 
        SnmpEngine(OctetString(hexValue=conf['snmpConfig']['snmpEngine'])), 
        UsmUserData(conf['snmpConfig']['snmpUser'], 
        conf['snmpConfig']['snmpAuthPassword'], 
        conf['snmpConfig']['snmpPrivacyPassword'], 
        authProtocol=authProtocol_type_1,
        privProtocol=privProtocol_type_1), 
        UdpTransportTarget((conf['receiverConfig']['host'], 
            conf['receiverConfig']['port'])),
        ContextData(),
        'trap',
        notification ))
```

Comment: Could you please add your trap request call for which you are getting this error?

Comment: Hi Rathin, I am just sending traps to a particular IP using sendNotification on a particular port.

Comment: def send_notification(conf, notification):
    next(sendNotification(
        SnmpEngine(OctetString(hexValue=conf['snmpConfig']['snmpEngine'])),
        UsmUserData(conf['snmpConfig']['snmpUser'], conf['snmpConfig']['snmpAuthPassword'], conf['snmpConfig']['snmpPrivacyPassword'],
                    authProtocol=authProtocol_type_1,
                    privProtocol=privProtocol_type_1),
        UdpTransportTarget((conf['receiverConfig']['host'], conf['receiverConfig']['port'])),
        ContextData(),
        'trap',
        notification
    ))

Comment: You didn't show the code to construct `notification` so we can only guess that you mistakenly use some value that falls out of the constraints set in the related MIB document. That's why PySMI kicked in and reported this error when verifying the value.